# 'Typing' animation on a Text with JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

So I tried drafting a method which would take a String and a Text, and would theoretically gradually output the String to that Text, as if someone was typing it out. However, all that happens is that the program pauses for a varying amount of time (due to the random values used in the pauses between each addition of a letter), and then the entire String is displayed.

```
public void keyboard(String string, Text tBox, Stage stage, Scene scene) {
    //generates a random number which later determines the amount of time the game pauses before
    //adding the next character
    Random number = new Random();

    //stores the length of a string (as an integer)
    int stringLen = string.length();

    //gets increased later
    int counter = 0;

    char[] chars = new char[(stringLen+1)];
    string.getChars(0, stringLen, chars, 0);

    String returnVal = "";

    do {
        returnVal += Character.toString(chars[counter]);
        counter += 1;
        tBox.setText(returnVal);
        pause((number.nextInt(3) + 1) * 100);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    } while (returnVal != string);

}
```

The pause method is as follows.

```
private void pause(int milliseconds) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(milliseconds);
    } catch (InterruptedException err) {
        System.err.println("Interrupted during pause.");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Halp Pls.

**EDIT:**

```
public void keyboard(String string, Text tBox) {
    final IntegerProperty counter = new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);
    Random number = new Random();
    int length = string.length();
    tBox.setFill(Color.WHITE);

    Timeline line = new Timeline();
    KeyFrame frame = new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds((number.nextInt(3) + 1) / 10),
        event -> { 
            if(counter.get() > length) {
                line.stop();
            } else {
                tBox.setText(string.substring(0, counter.get()));
                counter.set(counter.get() + 1);
            }
        });

    line.getKeyFrames().add(frame);
    line.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
    line.play();
}
```

Just for reference, the keyboard method starts when you type something into a TextField, which then checks whether the input is valid, and starts the animation based on that.

Comment: When Swing is calling your event handlers, it's not doing anything else, including updating the screen. Look into Swing Timers, which tell Swing to call an event handler after a delay.

Comment: Is there any way around this?

Comment: Also, I'm using JavaFX, but it probably doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are blocking the JavaFX Application thread when you are calling `Thread.sleep()` which is not the correct way of doing it.

If you need a animation you should use [`Timeline`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Timeline.html) instead.

> Timeline processes individual KeyFrame at or after specified time interval elapsed

```
import javafx.animation.Animation;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class Main extends Application {
    private final String str ="Itachi";

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Text text = new Text();
        VBox root = new VBox(text);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 330, 120, Color.WHITE);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        final IntegerProperty i = new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);
        Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
        KeyFrame keyFrame = new KeyFrame(
                Duration.seconds(1),
                event -> {
                    if (i.get() > str.length()) {
                        timeline.stop();
                    } else {
                        text.setText(str.substring(0, i.get()));
                        i.set(i.get() + 1);
                    }
                });
        timeline.getKeyFrames().add(keyFrame);
        timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
        timeline.play();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the point of having the 'i' as an IntegerProperty as opposed to just an int?

Comment: IntegerProperty is a JavaFX property which binds an int value. The purpose of using it here instead of an int is that the variables used inside lambdas should be final or effectively final. You cannot use an int and increment its value. Try it yourself and you will get to know :)

Comment: This time it simply doesn't render the text on the screen, rather, it just leaves the Text blank. I'm checking for errors, and I'll add the implementation above.

Comment: Oh wait I forgot to add the keyframes to the timeline. Herp derp.

Comment: Nah it still isn't working. I'll re-add the implementation.

Comment: Not quite sure. The implementation is added above. Basically, the animation starts when you type something into a TextField, and then it should start. The code you gave runs fine, but mine just leaves the Text blank.

Comment: @Rahul the error in your updated code is in your arithmetic.  3/10 = 0, because it uses [integer arithmetic](https://www.fpsct.org/uploaded/faculty/barront/apcs/Java_Arithmetic_Practice.pdf).  Use floating point arithmetic instead: 3/10.0=0.3

Comment: I'm a genius. Thanks :). **EDIT:** I always thought double arithmetic superseded integer arithmetic.